# Filter ForeignKey's available values on edit in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have a data like this:

```
[
    {ID: 1, SomeForeignKeyID: 1, FkLimitation: "Local"},
    {ID: 2, SomeForeignKeyID: 532, FkLimitation: "Foreign"}
]
```

Kendo Grid is using this data:

```
columns.Bound(m => m.ID);
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.SomeForeignKeyID, ViewBag.ForeignKeys as IEnumerable<object>, "Value", "Name");
```

Here's the problem: how to limit available values in ForeignKey column? For ex. - if FkLimitation == "Local" I'd like ForeignKey to allow to select values 1/2/3/4 and if FkLimitation == "Foreign" I'd like ForeignKey to allow to select values 532/232/432.

Edit mode is InCell.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky when it comes to In-Cell editing. First, you need to bind an edit event to the grid.

```
.Events(events => events.Edit("gridEdit"))
```

In the event handler, you will need to find out the data item of the current row. After that, you can create different filters based on the value of 'FkLimitation' and just apply it to the data source of the drop down list.

```
function gridEdit(e) {
    var inputLength = e.container.find("input[name='SomeForeignKeyID']").length;
    if (inputLength > 0) { // user is currently editing the SomeForeignKeyID column
        var dataItem = null;
        var row = $('#SomeForeignKeyID').closest('tr');
        if (row.length > 0) // retrieve the data item of the current row
            dataItem = $("#gridId").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(row);
        if (dataItem != null) {
            var filter = null;
            if (dataItem.FkLimitation == 'Local') {
                filter = {
                    logic: 'or',
                    filters: [
                        { field: 'Value', operator: 'eq', value: 1 },
                        { field: 'Value', operator: 'eq', value: 2 },
                        { field: 'Value', operator: 'eq', value: 3 },
                        { field: 'Value', operator: 'eq', value: 4 }
                    ]
                };
            } else if (dataItem.FkLimitation == 'Foreign') {
                filter = {
                    logic: 'or',
                    filters: [
                        { field: 'Value', operator: 'eq', value: 532 },
                        { field: 'Value', operator: 'eq', value: 232 },
                        { field: 'Value', operator: 'eq', value: 432 }
                    ]
                };
            }
            // filter/limit the values in the drop down list
            $('#SomeForeignKeyID').data('kendoDropDownList').dataSource.filter(filter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can access the model directly via `e.model` rather than fetching it from the closest row.